# Align text to top in html?

Tags: html, css

My code:

```
<div>
<input type="textarea">
</div>
```

How can I align text to the horizontal center and vertical top of the textarea?

Comment: There is no such input type as `textarea`. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-INPUT

Answer (score 5):

Like Dave mentioned there is no supported `type="textarea"` attribute for the `input` field. I think you want `<textarea>` like this:

```
<textarea class="alignCenter"></textarea>

.alignCenter {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/Jt34H/

Answer (score 0):

The styling of a Text-area is very limited. You could try us this [openWYSIWYG](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex16/openwysiwyg/readme.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just put,

> HTML

```
<textarea>some words</textarea>
```

> CSS

```
textarea
 {
    text-align:center;
}
```